# Flutter : Recover sqlite data in combobox

Tags: flutter, dropdown, sqflite

I want to recover data from my table and put them in my dropdown.
I get an error message : _TypeError (type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'List')
Thank you for your help

```
readData(table) async {
  var connection = await db;
  return await connection.query('SELECT nom_A FROM tab_A');
}


class DropdownMenuA extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownMenuA({super.key});
//Modif

  @override
  State<DropdownMenuA> createState() => _DropdownMenuAState();
}

class _DropdownMenuAState extends State<DropdownMenuA> {
  //String dropdownValueA = list1.first;
  List<String> listA = readData(Tab_A);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownMenu<String>(
      initialSelection: listA.first,
      onSelected: (String? value) {
        // This is called when the user selects an item.
        setState(() {
          //dropdownValueA = value!;
        });
      },
      dropdownMenuEntries: listA.map<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(value: value, label: value);
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: with a static list is OK :

Comment: const List<String> list1 = <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `await` keyword for the `Future` call. Like:

```
List<String> listA = await readData(Tab_A);
```

In order to use `await` keyword you must also use the `async` keyword as well like:

```
Future<void> fetchData() async {
    List<String> data = await readData(Tab_A);
    setState(() {
      listA = data;
    });
  }
```

And call this `fetchData()` function inside `initState()` function like:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }
```

Final code looks like:

```
class _DropdownMenuAState extends State<DropdownMenuA> {
  List<String> listA = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    List<String> data = await readData(Tab_A);
    setState(() {
      listA = data;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownMenu<String>(
      initialSelection: listA.isNotEmpty ? listA.first : null,
      onSelected: (String? value) {
      
        setState(() {
  
        });
      },
      dropdownMenuEntries: listA.map<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(value: value, label: value);
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Kindly, let me know if it works.

Comment: I have this message :

Comment: The await expression can only be used in an async function.

Comment: @Jef I have updated the answer. Kindly, have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much mlodhi for your responsiveness ! I'll do the tests tomorrow and keep you posted

Comment: Yes, I redo my code ! I can fill Combobox from db, I don't know how to use "stackoverflow" to put my code ?

Comment: @Jef if it worked then kindly, press the " up arrow " with my answer.  Also press the "tick" icon below the up arrow.

Comment: I have retrieve in my combobox the names, but I would like to retrieve the IDs of the names for Save to my table C : static const columnCId = '_id_C';
  static const columnCIdA = '_id_C_A';
  static const columnCIdB = '_id_C_B';

Comment: @Jef Please ask another question for that, and kindly mark this answer as an accepted answer for this question.

Comment: @Jef kindly, press the "up arrow" as well located above the green tick. I have also pressed the up arrow for your question.